# Upload function using forms publisher with the <browser>

Tags: teamsite, autonomy, interwoven

What necessary steps must be taken in order to upload a file from local machine to ContentCenter using Forms Publisher to create a DCR. As far as I understand the  instance only lets you browse files within the specified workarea. What I would like to do is use it to upload an image instead to a specified folder in the workarea instead.

Can anyone provide me with the steps/examples to solve this? Would be  really appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can do that with a custom plugin in Tiny MCE. Create a sevlet
   that has a browse button with upload functionality to teamsite
   workarea. Call that in Tiny MCE on click of an icon.
2. You can also create a CGI and call it in datacapture.cfg using callouts.
3. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: can you provide an example with the cgi callout?